# How Do I Handle Ampersands in Django URLs?

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

I have a Django site that uses item names to create viewer-friendly URLs.  For instance:

```
/item/DeluxeWidget/
```

I have an item that has an ampersand in the name:

```
/item/Red & Blue Widget/
```

The ampersand throws things off.  If I use {{ widget.name|fix_ampersands }}, the ampersand will be escaped as `&amp;` but it still isn't picked up in the URL pattern:

```
url(r"^widget/(?P<name>[0-9a-zA-Z&,. -]+)/$", 'site.views.widget' ),
```

In the view I use the captured name to do

```
Widget.objects.get(name=name)
```

What's the right combination of escaping, patterns, or filters to handle an ampersand in a URL?  I also expect to run into names with apostrophes in them.  Is there anything I should do to handle those too?

Comment: So the short answer is "don't".  Ampersands don't really belong in URLs anyhow.  Thank you for the suggestions -- it seems that SlugField is the ideal tool for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider using a [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) which can automatically be filled with a cleaned up version of another field suitable for use in URLs.

Comment: Yup - probably simpler for the OP instead of changing URL structure +1

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you're best off not doing that, and following an SO kind of pattern - let's use this page for an example (`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212960/how-do-i-handle-ampersands-in-django-urls`)

Then you can do:

```
url(r"^widget/(?P<widget_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<widget_name>(.*?)/$", 'site.views.widget' ),
```

Then:

- `{{ widget.name|fix_ampersands }}` becomes `{{ widget.name|slugify }}`
- `Widget.objects.get(name=name)` becomes `Widget.objects.get(pk=widget_id)`